# Creating elements in javascript and appending them to the DOM

Tags: javascript, appendchild, createelement

Here's a couple of small questions that I need help with...

I am trying to add multiple values to the select/option form but when I do that the javascript function ends up only adding the last one - here are the details for you to check out -

```
function addFields1(){
    var container = document.getElementById("container1");

    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Institution Name: "));

    var name = document.createElement("input");
    name.type = "text";
    name.id = "name";
    name.name = "certificate";
    name.size = 25;
    name.maxlength = 25;
    container.appendChild(name);

    var select = document.createElement("select"); //? how do I fix this up
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "College";
    option.innerHTML = "College";
    option.value = "Community College";
    option.innerHTML = "Community College";

    option.value = "High School";
    option.innerHTML = "High School";

    option.value = "Private";
    option.innerHTML = "Private";

    option.value = "University";
    option.innerHTML = "University";

    select.appendChild(option);
    container.appendChild(select);
}
```

When I call the function the only value that shows up is the very last one ("University") - the remaining values are not even on the menu when it drops down.

Another (similar) problem I am having is appending `<td>` and `<input>` elements and not being able to print any data when the eventhandler is called -

Here's the code for that below -

```
 function aFields1(){
    var container1 = document.getElementById("container");

    container1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Company: "));
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    var company = document.createElement("input");
    company.type = "text";
    company.id = "company";
    company.name = "company";
    company.size = 15;
    company.maxlength = 15;
    td.appendChild(company);
    container1.appendChild(td);
    container1.appendChild(company);
}
```

When i remove the `td` variable and td element, the information prints properly but if I don't do that it doesn't show up at all! Is there something wrong with what I did in this second function?

Answer (score 0):

With the `option` elements you actually need to re-run the `document.createElement('option')` otherwise javascript retains a reference to the originally added `option` element and only updates it (rather than appending a new element). This allows us to re-use the option variable.

The issue with the `<td>` element is similar... this line `container1.appendChild(company);` moves the company input element outside of the td element and into the container1 element.

I have cleaned up and fixed both of your functions:

```
function addFields1() {
    var container = document.getElementById("container1");

    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Institution Name: "));

    var name = document.createElement("input");
    name.type = "text";
    name.id = "name";
    name.name = "certificate";
    name.size = 25;
    name.maxlenth = 25;
    container.appendChild(name);

  //create select element and the option variable
    var select = document.createElement("select");
    var option;

  //before each option element we reassign the option variable to a new option element and append it to the select before moving to the next option item
    option = document.createElement("option");    
    option.value = "College";
    option.innerHTML = "College";
    select.appendChild(option);

    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "Community College";
    option.innerHTML = "Community College";
    select.appendChild(option);

    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "High School";
    option.innerHTML = "High School";
    select.appendChild(option);

    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "Private";
    option.innerHTML = "Private";
    select.appendChild(option);

    option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "University";
    option.innerHTML = "University";
    select.appendChild(option);

  //finally, we append the completed select element
    container.appendChild(select);
}

function aFields1() {
    var container1 = document.getElementById("container");

    container1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Company: "));
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    var company = document.createElement("input");
    company.type = "text";
    company.id = "company";
    company.name = "company";
    company.size = 15;
    company.maxlenth = 15;
  //append the company input element to the td element
    td.appendChild(company);
  //append the td element to the container1 element
    container1.appendChild(td);
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/jkpyafdx/)**